# In irb while defining a method named 'method'， wrong number of argument apperaed

Tags: ruby, irb

> after define a method named 'method' in irb/gry

```rb
def method
    puts 1
end
```

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
        33: from F:/Ruby27-x64/bin/irb.cmd:31:in `<main>'
        32: from F:/Ruby27-x64/bin/irb.cmd:31:in `load'
        31: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.3/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        30: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:399:in `start'
        29: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:470:in `run'
        28: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:470:in `catch'
        27: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:471:in `block in run'
        26: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:536:in `eval_input'
        25: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:134:in `each_top_level_statement'
        24: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:134:in `catch'
        23: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:135:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
        22: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:135:in `loop'
        21: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
        20: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:166:in `lex'
        19: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:517:in `block in eval_input'
        18: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:695:in `signal_status'
        17: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:518:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
        16: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/input-method.rb:262:in `gets'
        15: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable.rb:235:in `readmultiline'
        14: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable.rb:235:in `readmultiline'
        13: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/reline.rb:174:in `readmultiline'
        12: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/reline.rb:236:in `inner_readline'
        11: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/reline.rb:236:in `loop'
        10: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/reline.rb:237:in `block in inner_readline'
         9: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/reline.rb:266:in `read_io'
         8: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/reline.rb:266:in `loop'
         7: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/reline.rb:307:in `block in read_io'
         6: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/reline.rb:238:in `block (2 levels) in inner_readline'
         5: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/reline.rb:238:in `each'
         4: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/reline.rb:239:in `block (3 levels) in inner_readline'
         3: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/reline/line_editor.rb:837:in `input_key'
         2: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/reline/line_editor.rb:795:in `normal_char'
         1: from F:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/reline/line_editor.rb:721:in `process_key'
(irb):1:in `method': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
```

> but if I change its name, the bug fixed

after changing name, it ran correctly

[image: after changing name, it ran correctly]

I thought the reason of this bug is the method name in ruby can not be 'method'
but after I tried it in **RubyMine 2020.2**, it runned correctly
I am confused.

in RubyMine
[image: in RubyMine]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the [`Object#method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method) method. It is *never* a good idea to overwrite a core Ruby method.

In particular, both IRb and Pry support auto-completion while you type, they support documentation, and many other things. And guess what method they use to get a [`Method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html) object that they can work with?

So, what is happening is that IRb is calling `method(some_method_name)` to get access to some method, but you have overwritten the `Object#method` method with a method that takes no argument.

Don't mess with Ruby's core methods. And if you are using IRb, *especially* don't mess with core methods that are used by IRb.